# Kotlin await not suspending?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

i have the following code in Kotlin

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    runBlocking {
        val async1 = async {
            println("1st")
            delay(2000)
            println("1st end")
        }
        val async2 = async {
            println("2nd")
            delay(1000)
            println("2nd end")
        }

        async1.await()
        async2.await()

        println("end")
    }
}
```

The output is

```
1st
2nd
2nd end
1st end
end
```

My understanding was, that `await()` is a suspending function, meaning the execution is "paused" there. So i thought, that actually first `async1` would be executed, and THEN `async2` would be executed. So i expected the output to be

```
1st
1st end
2nd
2nd end    
end
```

What obviously happened was, that both `async1` and `async2` where executed in parallel, which can be seen as the output of `async1` is sandwiched between the outputs of `async2`.

So my concrete question is now: Why did Kotlin not suspend on `async1`, but concurrently started `async2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await()` will suspend coroutine it run's in - which is your main block (and a thread  `runBlocking()` is running, because it's blocking), so `async2.await()` will not be called, unless `async1` is finished.
But since execution of `async()` function is started immediately and will be executed by default on background thread pool, it will not be blocked.
You can check it by adding

```
 async1.await()
 println("between")
 async2.await()
```

and see, that "between" will always be printed after "1st end"

If you want coroutines to run sequentially - use `runBlocking()` builder (or in most cases no need to use coroutines at all for such cases)

The idea of async/await is to run tasks in parallel and don't block other tasks while you waiting for results of one of them.

Comment: `runBlocking` isn't at all about sequential execution, but about blocking until the coroutine is done. Both `withContext(Default) { task() }` or `async { task }.await()` make `task` execute sequentially with the current coroutine.

Comment: thx DmitryBorodin! i was not aware, that `async` starts immediately.

Answer (score 2):

> Why did Kotlin not suspend on `async1`, but concurrently started `async2`?

`async` spawns a new task in the background. The task starts executing right away. You have no control over its suspension and there's a whole class of use cases where it never gets suspended. We often use `async` to submit blocking tasks to a thread pool.

`await` suspends the current coroutine until the task has completed and produced its result. It has no effect on the execution of the task. The task will run to completion even if you never call `await`.

If you specifically want to fire the task only when you call `await`, you can specify `start = LAZY`:

```
runBlocking {
    val async1 = async(start = LAZY) {
        println("1st")
        delay(2000)
        println("1st end")
    }
    val async2 = async(start = LAZY) {
        println("2nd")
        delay(1000)
        println("2nd end")
    }

    async1.await()
    async2.await()

    println("end")
}
```

This reliably prints in the order you expected.